# Localization of a WPF ClickOnce application with LocBaml

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, localization, clickonce, locbaml

I'm trying to use the LocBaml way (this might be my mistake) to localize a WPF application, but this application is deployed with ClickOnce and the publishing process doesn't pick up the localized .resource.dll.

I do add the files to my ClickOnce manifest, and I can see that this part works because when I launch the application, I get an error saying that the application can't find fr\LocalizationTest.resource.dll. (So at least it knows it should be there...)

The normal way to include a file in a ClickOnce application is simply to add it in the Project Properties -> Publish -> Application Files menu, but my localized resources are not in there.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out adding a dummy `Resources.fr.resx` in the Properties folder fixed the problem. With that the publishing process picked up the translated .dll and the ClickOnce application worked as expected.